# Error using console.log on an Object, created with no prototypes && Accessing arrays with Stringed properties worked.. how?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph, null, javascript-objects

I am reading Eloquent JavaScript 3rd Edition (https://eloquentjavascript.net/), and in Chapter 7, Marjin Haverbeke created a graph data structure, using this function.

```
function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }

  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}
```

```
const roads = ["Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Post Office", "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Shop"];
```

`const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);`

So then I tried
   `console.log(roadGraph);`

And it gave me this error:

`TypeError: obj.toString is not a function. (In 'obj.toString()', 'obj.toString' is undefined)`

And then when I replace

`let graph = Object.create(null);` (line 2 in `buildGraph` function)

With

`let graph = {};`

And `console.log(roadGraph);`

It returns a graph-like object of arrays of expected strings.

Meanwhile if I use `let graph=[];` 
it returns an empty array, when I  use `console.log(roadGraph);`

But if I `console.log(roadGraph.property);` it displays correctly the value of the `property`

Please I need a Javascript guru to explain why these things happen.

- What is the main reason for creating an Object with no prototypes in this function.
- Why can’t I look at all properties and values of the object created with no prototype at once.
- It displays an empty array, when I try looking at the values, but then if I try accessing a value in the array, with a “**Stringed property**” it displays correctly the value of the **Stringed Property.**   *Does this means array names/properties can be strings??* (Because I was told arrays could only be accessed with **indexes[numbers]**)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error when using the code in your question. Using Chrome.

Comment: Your code works fine on Firefox too

Comment: roadGraph is not an array with stringed properties, it is an object. [What is the main reason for creating an Object with no prototypes in this function.](https://davidwalsh.name/object-create-null) In short; if you want to create a dict/hash then `Object.create(null)` guarantees no properties can be added to the object instance through it's prototype.

Comment: @HMR  I was using “Scriptable” and “Javascript Everywhere” I just tried it with chrome and it worked.

Comment: @HMR try making graph an array.. you’ll see what I’m talking about.. it will be an array and yet it can be accessed with stringed properties. I just did on chrome.

Comment: An array is an object and everything is mutable in JavaScript so `const arr = [];arr.someKey='some value'` will work but you're not supposed to do that. The variable `graph` is an object because you will be setting values using strings as key and JavaScript does not have Associative arrays, only indexed.

Comment: @HMR I’m not supposed to do that.. okay.. but if I choose to (which might be bad practice conventionally) It works, and it works fine. I was confused because I was told array keys can only be indexes, which according to what you did now, is **wrong**  because it can be strings. Getting to know the difference between something not existing and that it actually exists and works but is bad practice gives me satisfaction. 

Comment: After playing a little bit with it, I can now see, it is even a way of hiding values inside an array.  @HMR  Please tell me, is there a way I can print all of the values of an array that has some of its properties/keys as Strings, alongside its values that has its keys as normal indexes[numbers] all at once?

Comment: I think you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: @HMR Bam, it worked! The only con about it is that even though I added the stringed keys first, they appear at the end.. but it’s fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the main reason for creating an Object with no prototypes in this function.

The object was created with no prototype so that it couldn't be affected by additions to a prototype and was a fresh start to define as the programmer saw fit. It's not really necessary, but it does make the object more separate from traditional ones.

> Why can’t I look at all properties and values of the object created with no prototype at once.

This is simply because without a prototype, the object won't be able to access the `Object.toString()` method that other objects have access to through their prototype chain. If you were to create your own `toString` function, or take the existing one and put it on this object, then the object's properties would be able to be converted to a string just like any other object. Basically, this is a side effect or having no prototype. It also shows what that really means-- none of the traditional object methods work on this one without workarounds.

> It displays an empty array, when I try looking at the values, but then if I try accessing a value in the array, with a “Stringed property” it displays correctly the value of the Stringed Property. Does this means array names/properties can be strings?? (Because I was told arrays could only be accessed with indexes[numbers])

Arrays are actually just a variation of a normal object. They can have string-indexed properties as well as number-indexed properties. However, this should not be done in most cases, unless you know what you're doing and are trying to eg. add a method to your array. (Array methods, like `Array.splice()`, are named properties; this is an example of why having named properties on arrays can be useful).